How to decrypt ZTE F670 router's encrypted config.bin with payload type 5 with telnet access?
I’m from Indonesia.
I have a ZTE F670 (Software Version V6.0.10) router provided by my ISP, and I'm trying to retrieve certain credentials stored in the configuration.
Previously, with a different router, I could download the config.xml file directly from the web interface and extract the needed information. However, with this new router, the backup file is in an encrypted config.bin format.
So far, I've tried the following:

Downloaded the config.bin file from the router's web interface. Used tools like the ZTE config utility, but the router appears to use a newer encryption algorithm (payload type 5), which isn't supported by the tools I've found.
I tried to use the serial number as an encryption key, without success.
Then I tried using https://github.com/mkst/zte-config-utility but no success.

Telnet are open and I can access root user. I can download telnet file like cspd, dataprotocol and etc… but don’t know to use it.
Can someone help me decrypt the config.bin file, or suggest any tools that work with newer ZTE models?

I’m voting to close this question because it either belongs on Software Recommendations or Cryptography

It cannot be done. Previous devices used weaker ciphers.
